# I write four pages with GetX, such as Page1,Page2,Page3,Page4, I use Get.toNamed(xxx)

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I write four pages with GetX, such as Page1,Page2,Page3,Page4, I use Get.toNamed(xxx)
Page1->Page2->Page3->Page4->Page1, then I changed some data in second Page1, turn back to first Page1, I found something was wrong, Data of second Page1 found in first Page1, I think first Page1 and second Page1 are same one, But I want they are different，can you help me to resolve this problem, thank you very much!

Comment: Show us the code

Answer (score 0):

A bool value can also be used to separate the page from the first view.

```
class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isFirstView;
  const Page1({
    Key? key,
    this.isFirstView = false,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Page 1')),
      body: isFirstView
          ? Container(
              color: Colors.yellow,
              child: const Text('First View'),
            )
          : Center(
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Get.to(const Page1(isFirstView: true,));
                },
                child: const Text('Second View Button'),
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```